# HashMap - Changing key value

Tags: java, weak-references

```
HashMap<StringBuilder, StringBuilder> aMap = new 
       HashMap<StringBuilder, StringBuilder>();

StringBuilder emp = new StringBuilder("Stack");
StringBuilder val = new StringBuilder("Programmer");

aMap.put(emp, val);
emp = new StringBuilder("sss");
System.out.println(aMap);`
```

Though `emp` value is chnaged, it does not reflect in a HashMap. Is it because HashMap uses some kind of copy constructor while putting a new value?

Now coming to WeakHashMap :

```
WeakHashMap<StringBuilder, StringBuilder> aMap1 = 
            new WeakHashMap<StringBuilder, StringBuilder>();
    StringBuilder emp1 = new StringBuilder("WeakStack");
    StringBuilder val1 = new StringBuilder("Programmer");
aMap1.put(emp1, val1);
emp1 = new StringBuilder("WeakStack1");
```

After some GC calls, the `aMap1` becomes empty. Why so? Is it because the key pointing to doesnot exist anymore?

Update : I understand from the answers that key is referenced from HashMap, so when `emp`(mutable key) in above `HashMap` is changed by appending a String to it, like `emp.append("changed")`, it reflects in `HashMap`. Same is true for `WeakHashMap`(if a mutable key is changed/updated, the change is reflected). Which means that key is being referenced from WeakHashMap.

Could anyone please explain what is `WeakHashMap` implementation different that the key can be garbage collected though its being referenced?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emp = new StringBuilder("sss");` doesn't affect the entry that's already in the `HashMap` (the one created by the statement `new StringBuilder("Stack");`), since the `HashMap` contains its own reference to the `StringBuilder` instance that was originally referred by `emp`. It doesn't create a copy of the `StringBuilder` instance, it only keeps a copy of the reference.

On the other hand, with `WeakHashMap`, the presence of a key in the `WeakHashMap` doesn't prevent it from being garbage collected, so if there is no other reference to the key you put in the map, the GC can release that instance. Therefore, after you assign a new instance to `emp1`, only the map contains a reference to the original instance it referred to, and the GC can release it.

Here's the relevant Javadoc reference :

> An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded by the garbage collector

EDIT :

As for how the implementation of `WeakHashMap` is different, the `Entry` of a `WeakHashMap` extends `WeakReference<Object>`, which is an instance that refers to another instance (the key of the entry in this case) and doesn't prevent its referent from being released by the GC.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. I have another question. Please see the update

Comment: @user2296988 see edit. Read about `WeakReference` for more details.